# Querying index in DynamoDB results in primary key error

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am finding it difficult to query GSI on a table. Code sample below results in key error which relates to primary key despite the fact I am using an index.

Table definition:

```
TableName : config.user_table,
KeySchema: [       
    { AttributeName: "user", KeyType: "HASH"}
],
AttributeDefinitions: [       
    { AttributeName: "user", AttributeType: "S" },
    { AttributeName: "activation_code", AttributeType: "S" },
],
GlobalSecondaryIndexes: [
    {
        IndexName: "activation_code_index",
        KeySchema: [
            {AttributeName: "activation_code", KeyType: "HASH"}
        ],
        Projection: {
            ProjectionType: "ALL"
        },
        ProvisionedThroughput: {
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,"WriteCapacityUnits": 1
        }
    }
],
ProvisionedThroughput: {       
    ReadCapacityUnits: 10, 
    WriteCapacityUnits: 10
}
```

Query definition:

```
var params = {
    TableName: config.user_table,
    IndexName: "activation_code_index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "activation_code = :code", 
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":code": code
    }
};
return dcl.query(params).promise();
```

Error:

```
message: 'One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key user in the item',
code: 'ValidationException',
```

Comment: Try using double quotes around `activation_code_index` in your code. The standard for JSON requires double quotes, not single.

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman Moved from single to double quotes but still have the same issue.

Comment: only other thing that struck me as unusual was the fact that ther eis no "CREATE:" tag in your table definition just before the secondary index. Are you sure the index is actually created

Comment: @JeffreyPhillipsFreeman I can see the index in the DynamoDB UI. I can also query the index in the UI, the problem seems to be querying over aws-sdk.

Comment: Sorry I'm at a loss then :(

Comment: This looks allright. Cant see a problem. Maybe add a screenshot of UI or your source code. It could be something you are missing and come out of what you have posted

Comment: Try changing `":code": code` to `":code": {"S": code}`